# Broken Git Tree

Tags: git

I recently inherited a project and found out that the git repo tree is broken.[image]

The first blue commit contains ALL the code of the app plus some changes in the commit.

I have two questions.

1. How is such a state created?
2. Is it possible to fix this tree. Perhaps Push the head of the blue sub branch on the red master branch?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: To create such a branch (now) you can do `git branch --orphan`, it is usually called "unrelated branches". You can merge them but have to specify `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

Comment: Is your view set to date or ancestor order?

Comment: View is set to ancestor order

Comment: Tried merging and git had a 100 conflicts. Is it possible to just force this blue tree on the older red one?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: `git checkout --orphan` (followed by a new commit); not `git branch --orphan`. The allow unrelated histories flag was new in Git 2.9; before that, `git merge` just shrugged at unrelated histories and merged anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unrelated histories can be joined together using `git filter-branch`. Here's an excerpt from the manpage:

```
To set a commit (which typically is at the tip of another history) to be the
parent of the current initial commit, in order to paste the other history behind
the current history:

    git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p <graft-id>/"' HEAD

(if the parent string is empty - which happens when we are dealing with the
initial commit - add graftcommit as a parent). Note that this assumes history
with a single root (that is, no merge without common ancestors happened). If
this is not the case, use:

    git filter-branch --parent-filter \
            'test $GIT_COMMIT = <commit-id> && echo "-p <graft-id>" || cat' HEAD

or even simpler:

    git replace --graft $commit-id $graft-id
    git filter-branch $graft-id..HEAD
```

In your case, `$commit-id` is the first blue commit and `$graft-id` is the last red.

---

Here's an example of the complete procedure:

Let's create a repo and some red commits:

```
$ git init
$ echo a >a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m c1
[master (root-commit) 6a6b98f] c1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
$ echo b >>a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m c2
[master d91d385] c2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now create an unrelated branch `o1` and add some blue commits:

```
$ git checkout --orphan=o1
Switched to a new branch 'o1'
$ echo c >>a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m c3
[o1 (root-commit) ed2b106] c3
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a
$ echo d >>a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m c4
[o1 5b655a6] c4
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Check that we got what we wanted:

```
$ git log --format=short --graph --all
* commit 5b655a615f8a729c123d89180ca1928451b465b2 (HEAD -> o1)
| 
|     c4
| 
* commit ed2b106d7bd0ffef317a723f2921808bc8ad9f45

      c3

* commit d91d385c7811ba07f4092133c435b55323562686 (master)
| 
|     c2
| 
* commit 6a6b98fca7150839f607d9d55c6b9f10861375f8

      c1
```

Create a graft commit for `ed2b106` (c3, first blue) with `d91d385` (c2, last red) as its new parent:

```
$ git replace --graft ed2b106d7bd0ffef317a723f2921808bc8ad9f45 d91d385c7811ba07f4092133c435b55323562686
$ git log --format=short --graph --all
* commit 5b655a615f8a729c123d89180ca1928451b465b2 (HEAD -> o1)
| 
|     c4
| 
* commit ed2b106d7bd0ffef317a723f2921808bc8ad9f45 (replaced)
| 
|     c3
|   
| * commit 4656e5bca003770b1a35aff10e3ffb51f7fb1ad9
|/
|       c3
| 
* commit d91d385c7811ba07f4092133c435b55323562686 (master)
| 
|     c2
| 
* commit 6a6b98fca7150839f607d9d55c6b9f10861375f8

      c1
```

We got `4656e5b` (fixed c3) as a replacement with fixed parents, but that replacement is only local, so we now need to rewrite all the blue commits:

```
$ git filter-branch d91d385c7811ba07f4092133c435b55323562686..HEAD
Rewrite 5b655a615f8a729c123d89180ca1928451b465b2 (2/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
Ref 'refs/heads/o1' was rewritten
$ git log --format=short --graph
* commit 2cf6b0d3a0ee2deff99bbe327d065f90c82c1c2b (HEAD -> o1)
| 
|     c4
| 
* commit 4656e5bca003770b1a35aff10e3ffb51f7fb1ad9
| 
|     c3
| 
* commit d91d385c7811ba07f4092133c435b55323562686 (master)
| 
|     c2
| 
* commit 6a6b98fca7150839f607d9d55c6b9f10861375f8

      c1
```

The `4656e5b` (fixed c3) was already good (same as `ed2b106`, the original c3, just with different parent), but `5b655a6` (c4) was rewritten so that its parent is `4656e5b` (fixed c3) instead of `ed2b106` (original c3). We can now safely drop the replacement as `ed2b106` is no longer used in our history:

```
$ git replace -d ed2b106d7bd0ffef317a723f2921808bc8ad9f45
Deleted replace ref 'ed2b106d7bd0ffef317a723f2921808bc8ad9f45'
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that doing this results in a *new and different* repository (well, different from the graft point forwards), which essentially means that everyone using a clone must discard their old clone and get a new one.

Comment: Wow! That was super helpful!

Comment: I did all the steps, worked flawlessly. Thanks! My git tree is broken no more!